# MQTT broker publisher-side or subscriber-side?

Tags: windows, embedded, mqtt, broker

I'm trying to implement a communication between two entities (we will say a controller and a device). The controller is a Windows application running on Windows 10 and the device is an embedded system. I would like to use MQTT protocol to transmit messages between them. The problem is the location of the broker. Should I implement the broker in the embedded system considering that it could be have more devices connected to the controller in the future, or should I use an existing broker application as proposed by Mosquitto ?

Thank you in advance,

Best regards

Comment: Install mosquitto in the PC? An MQTT server can be heavy for an embedded device.

Comment: Not true, every Dyson fan has a built in MQTT broker...

Comment: This will have to be a personal choice based on the details of your system, as such the question can only get opinion based answers and as such is probably off topic.

Comment: You're definitely right, I asked this question to have the opinion of MQTT users. I should have asked the question differently to be clearer.